# SQL Server Management Studio error 948

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried to attach a database (.mdf) file and I got this error:

```
Attach database failed for Server '...\SQLINSTANCE'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Additional information:
     An exception occured while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
     (Microfost.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
          The database 'DBName' cannot be opened because it is version 782. This server supports version 706 or earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'DBName'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)
```

P.S. I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express, and database 'DBName' has been made in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Are you trying to put a 2008 mdf to a 2012 server?

Comment: 782 is 2014, isn't it?

Comment: You are trying to attach a db from a newer version of SQL to an older version

Comment: take a look at this http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817399/vs-2013-express-does-not-work-with-sql-servewr-express-2014-ctp2

Comment: @dean I just figured that out

Comment: @dean I thought so too, but I'm experiencing an error in 2014 saying that the database is 782, but SQL Server only support 706 and below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have source control

1. Rollback the mdf file
2. Rollback the idf file (log file) to the same version

I had a similar problem and this solution fixed is.

If you do not have source control and you are using Code First

1. Backup the mdf and idf files
2. Delete the mdf and idf files in the solution explorer
3. Create a new database from project->add new item->data->SQL server database
4. In the package manager console write "Enable-migrations" then "Add-migration init" then "Update-database" to create your tables in the database.

For me, if things got too complicated, I would just recreate the project and copy the code :)